# How to Get Additional DB Value from Selected Value in jQuery AutoComplete?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I am creating a software inside WordPress (specifically as a plugin) and it does the following;

- Has 2 input boxes that run devBridge Autocomplete to a database table of locations. (Origin and Destination) (they are loaded via HTML in a shortcode function, so it is displayed via a shortcode)
- Has a Google Maps API script that generates a map. It generates 2 markers between these selected locations and draws a line between them.
- In order to get the places for Google, it selects the lat and lng values from the locations database based on the location the user selected. I.e.) User selects Milan, MI, and the onSelect of autocomplete puts the lat and lng values into variables.
- The software does this to calculate distance between 2 places and use it to calculate a price via a formula using the distance as a variable. Although, I am not going to fully explain the other parts because I just need help with a specific part.

I have the locations table setup like this;

- id: int(5) - id of the location, i.e.) 1
- location: varchar(24) - name of the location, i.e.) Milan, MI
- destGroup: varChar(24) - name of destination group, i.e.) Detroit-Ann Arbor-Flint, MI
- lat: decimal(8,5) - latitude of location, i.e.) 39.776583
- lng: decimal(9,5) - longitude of location, i.e.) -106.917459

**My code**:

HTML

```
/** -- Origin Search Function --
* Builds the Raw HTML for the input box that is needed to create the location live search tool. Used to build shortcode that displays the box and suggestions for the origin search tool.
**/
public function origin_search( $atts ) {
        $orig = "<center><input type='text' id='origin' name='origin' style='color:#fff;background-color:#363636;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:40px;border-width:1px;border-radius:5px' autocomplete='off'/></center>";
    return $orig;
}

/** -- Destination Search Function --
* Builds the Raw HTML for the input box that is needed to create the location live search tool. Used to build shortcode that displays the box and suggestions for the destination search tool.
**/
public function destination_search( $atts ) {
    $dest = "<center><input type='text' id='destination' name='destination' style='color:#fff;background-color:#363636;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:40px;border-width:1px;border-radius:5px' autocomplete='off'/><div id='destination-suggest'></div></center>";
    return $dest;
}

/** -- Map Display Function --
* Builds the Raw HTML for the map to display. Used to build shortcode that displays the map on the frontend.
**/
public function rail_map( $atts ) {
    $map = "<div id='map' style='height:400px;width:600px'></div></br><div id='msg' style='visibility: hidden'></div>";
    return $map;
}

//Registers all shortcode functions into WordPress to allow them to run.
public function register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'origin-search', array( $this, 'origin_search') );
    add_shortcode( 'destination-search', array( $this, 'destination_search') );
    add_shortcode( 'rail-map', array( $this, 'rail_map') );
}
```

PHP

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-content/plugins/rail-rate-engine/includes/class-rail-rate-engine-pdo-config.php');
global $wpdb;
$query = isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : FALSE;
if ($query) {
// escape values passed to db to avoid sql-injection
            $depts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location LIKE '".$query."%' ORDER BY location ASC LIMIT 0,10" );

            $suggestions = array();
            $data = array();
            $destGroup = array();
            $lat = array();
            $lng = array();

            foreach($depts as $row) {
                $suggestions[] = $row->location;
                $data[] = $row->id;
                $destGroup[] = $row->destGroup
                $lat[] = $row->lat;
                $lng[] = $row->lng;
            }
            $response = array(
                'query' => $query,
                'suggestions' => $suggestions,
                'data' => $data,
                'destGroup' => $destGroup,
                'lat' => $lat,
                'lng' => $lng,
            );
            echo json_encode($response);
}
```

JS

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#origin').autocomplete({

// add the way to the file with database query
        noCache: false,
        preventBadQueries: true,
        minChars: 0,
       serviceUrl: '/wp-content/plugins/rail-rate-engine/includes/class-rail-rate-engine-location.php',
// callback function:
        onSelect: function(value, data){ 
            var orglocation = value;
            var orgid = data;
            var olat = lat;
            var olng = lng;
        },
  }); 
  $('#destination').autocomplete({

// add the way to the file with database query
        noCache: false,
        preventBadQueries: true,
        minChars: 0,
       serviceUrl: '/wp-content/plugins/rail-rate-engine/includes/class-rail-rate-engine-location.php',
// callback function:
        onSelect: function(value, data){ 
            var destlocation = value;
            var destid = data;
            var destgroup = destGroup;
            var dlat = lat;
            var dlng = lng;
        },
  });
});
```

Google Maps

```
  var map;
function initMap() {
  var olat = olat;
  var olng = olng;
  var dlat = dlat;
  var dlng = dlng;

  // The map, centered on The Geographic Center of the United States. 
  const center = {lat: 39.8283459, lng: -98.5794797};
  const options = {zoom: 15, scaleControl: true, center: center};
  map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), options);
  // Locations of landmarks
  const orig = {lat: olat, lng: olng};
  const dest = {lat: dlat, lng: dlng};
  // The markers for origin and destination.
  var mk1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: orig, map: map});
  var mk2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: dest, map: map});
}
```

WP Enqueue Scripts

```
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->rail_rate_engine, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/rail-rate-engine-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', false, array('jquery')); //Because it ships with WordPress
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', false, array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('autocomplete', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.26/jquery.autocomplete.js',array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=AIzaSyAf2-e6S3Gj275e_FVTDjp9kFn-iMElNSc&callback=initMap', array(), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->rail_rate_engine, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/class-rail-rate-engine-map.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
```

**The issue**: I need help with getting the autocomplete to store the variables. I don't know the proper way of getting the php output aka JSON response to include an extra column in the response for lat and lng so I can have the autocomplete read it and store it as a variable, so then I can use it for Google Maps API. I tried in the code above, but obviously it does not work and it produces errors.

If anyone knows the proper way of getting those extra database column values to be passed through the autocomplete onSelect function as saved variables, I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance.